# How do I make a console.log() print the value selected on a range input?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

```
input.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let input = document.getElementById('myRange').value
    console.log(input.value)
    if (input === '1'){
        theme1()
    }
    if (input === '2'){
        theme2()
    }
})
```

The `console.log(input.value)` shows `undefined`. I want them shows me the value selected on input every time I click on it.

Comment: you're already accessing the `.value` in the value you assign to `input`, so you just want to `console.log(input)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you're setting `input` to the value and then trying to do `.value` so essentially you're doing `input.value.value`

Changing your code to

```
input.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const value = document.getElementById('myRange').value
    console.log(value)
    if (value === '1'){
        theme1()
    }
    if (value === '2'){
        theme2()
    }
})
```

Will solve it